# RBAC feature in flask

Tags: python-2.7, flask, rbac, flask-admin

I'm trying to create a [Role Based Access Control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) in my application dashboard. I have done it in PHP using Yii2 framework [GitHub](https://github.com/ashish3x3/Media-Asset-Management-System) but I'm confused how to get it done in flask using python. I'm new to python.

I can't provide more details as I'm not clear with this.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/

Answer (score 3):

There is such an extension for flask already: [Flask-RBAC](https://flask-rbac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). If you want to code one yourself you should inspect the code of the existing one. Or you can use it in your applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Casbin. Casbin supports both PHP (PHP-Casbin) and Python (PyCasbin). It also has the Yii middleware and Flask middleware. Here's the FLask middleware: https://github.com/pycasbin/flask-authz